# Why does 'Find in files' shows files outside solution

Tags: c#, jetbrains-ide, rider

My solution consists 3 projects, and only `.cs` files. Now, I want to search across whole solution and find every occurence of word: `var`. For some reason, some weird files are displayed in output window (like: `http-dynamid-variables.json`):
[image]

I know I can limit searches to `*.cs`, but in a real scenario I would search across different file formats. Why does rider shows that `json` files? I can't see them in my solution at all

Comment: Can you see those files in the file system?

Comment: @mjwills I found them in `C:\Program Files\JetBrains\JetBrains Rider 2021.1.3\plugins\restClient\lib\restClient.jar!\com\intellij\ws\rest\client\stubs`. But its fat away from my solution..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are talking about this issue:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-63634

It is fixed in latest Rider versions (2021.1.4 and 2021.2.EAP)

Comment: Is 2021.1.4 available to download? On the Jetbrain's page, latest version is still: 2021.2.3

Comment: Probably it was not released yet, but will be very soon. Like next days

Comment: I have installed Rider yestarday and I am very disappointed. This bug makes this IDE useless to me. The worst part is that this bug had been known for over 1 month and still isnt fixed in stable release.